# Special Builds With Blender

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I installed a special build from GraphicAll.org for blender. It gave me a .7z file after the download. How do I install this into blender or use it for blender?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to "install" that file into blender. That file IS a blender version! You just need to decompress that file with 7zip (http://www.7-zip.org/), a free open source compression/decompression utility which handles many formats. 7z is usually more efficient than .zip so is often used as alternative for big files.

Comment: What is the difference between that file and the blender on blender.org?

Comment: graphicall is usually hosting special builds that differ from the official ones: since blender is free open source, anyone can get it, modify, build, and share it on graphicall. this sometimes allow people to try experimental features -  which can be also broken, or broken on your platform. My advice: you can't trust totally who shares them. Be sure to get some more info about the author or that specific build before using it. Even without bad intentions, that build could by mistake damage your pc or do other bad things. Official versions are safe, and you can always trust them.